# Method not being called with due to uint8_t conditions - objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, conditional-statements, uint8t

Hey guys I have these two methods; and I cannot seem to figure out why my `digitalSMSCheck` isn't being called.

My method `setInput` retrieves a `uint8_t` object from an outside source that is constantly changing, so it is never a static value. Then the setInput method calls the other method; `digitalInputAlertSystem` which passes in the old `uint8_t` object and generates a new `uint8_t` object to compare the two.

I then want to traverse 8 bits of the `uint8_t` object with a for-loop which will check each bit to see if it is assigned the same value as the original `uint8_t` object from the `setInput` method if the two `uint8_t` objects are not the same; it will then find where they are differing bit-wise and send a SMS alert via the `digitalSMSCheck` method (which is what is not calling properly).

```
    - (void)setInput:(NCDigitalInput *)input
{
    NSLog(@"setInput called");
    uint8_t value = input.value;
    self.inputLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%0.2X",value];
    for (UISwitch *temp in switchArrayIn)
    {
        temp.on = (value & 1);
        value >>= 1;
    }
    [self digitalInputAlertSystem:input :value];
}



 - (void) digitalInputAlertSystem:(NCDigitalInput *)input :(uint8_t) oldValue{
        NSLog(@"digitalInputALertSystem called");

        uint8_t value = input.value;
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *baseString;
        NSString *smsString;

        for (int i = 0; i<switchArrayIn.count; i++){
            if((value) != (oldValue)){
                if((value & 1) ==  1){
                    baseString = [defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%d",i]];
                    smsString = [baseString stringByAppendingFormat:@" has turned on"];
                    if(![defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%dRecentlyAlerted",i]]){
                        [self digitalSMSCheck:i :smsString];
                        [defaults setBool:TRUE forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%dRecentlyAlerted",i]];
                    }
                }
                else if((value & 1) !=  1){
                    baseString = [defaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%d",i]];
                    smsString = [baseString stringByAppendingFormat:@" has turned off"];
                    if(![defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%dRecentlyAlerted",i]]){
                        [self digitalSMSCheck:i :smsString];
                        [defaults setBool:TRUE forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%dRecentlyAlerted",i]];
                    }
                }
            }
            value >>=1;
            oldValue >>=1;
            //[defaults setBool:(value & i) forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%dValueBool",i]];

        }
    }
```

Here is the digitalSMSCheck method:

```
- (void) digitalSMSCheck:(int) pinNum :(NSString *)pinChangedNotificationValue{

    //the time permitted between alerts. A pin, when sending an alert, will be unable to send another for 3 seconds.
    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create(("com.my.cool.new.queue"), DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
        double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds*NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, myQueue, ^(void){
        NSLog(@"The method DigitalSMSCheck was called");
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        for (int i = 0; i<=7; i++) {
            if ((i == pinNum) && !([defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%dRecentlyAlerted",pinNum%8]])) {
                [defaults setBool:FALSE forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalInput%dRecentlyAlerted",pinNum%8]];
                NSLog(@"The boolean for checking was successfully resetted to false; 1");
            }
        }
        for (int i = 8; i<=15; i++) {
            if ((i == pinNum) && !([defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalOutput%dRecentlyAlerted",pinNum%8]])) {
                [defaults setBool:FALSE forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalOutput%dRecentlyAlerted",pinNum%8]];


                NSLog(@"The boolean for checking was successfully resetted to false; 2");
            }
        }


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            [appDelegate watchPins:pinChangedNotificationValue];
            [self updateInput];
            [self updateOutput];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:FALSE];

            [self setColors];
            [self setOutputSwitches];
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Yes I have; it I even added some NSLogs and it appears that the boolean flag for 'digitalInput%dRecentlyAlerted' is what the issue is being called by; anywhere that flag exists the code does not reach.

Comment: When are you expecting this value to be TRUE? the only time that you set it in the code you set it to FALSE after one of the conditions being that it is FALSE. If this value is always FALSE then you're not going to get to the `digitalSMSCheck:` section of code.

Comment: @JamesSnook I expect it to be true when an alert was already sent; so as to not have the system send the user too many text messages from the SMS service. It should set the boolean to true saying that a "message was recently sent" and then falsify the boolean when the async_dispatch queue finishes after it's delay so that the application may feel free to send another alert if necessary.

Comment: So when you do this `(i == pinNum) && !([defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"digitalOutput%dRecentlyAlerted",pinNum%8]]` don't you want to check that the recentlyAlerted is TRUE (not FALSE) so you can change it to FALSE? i.e. if you were recently alerted and the time period has passed you want to change it to say you weren't recently alerted (rather than if you weren't recently alerted change it to you weren't recently alerted?)

Comment: Yes; I see what you mean - that makes sense. Bad copy paste on my part. Thanks man!